# How to get columns/fields data of one row in temporary table from multiple select queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the results of the two select queries to be data for different columns of one row in the temporary table. But not as a second row.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_temp_table 
(SELECT U.c_user_id, UL.c_timestamp FROM t_user U INNER JOIN t_user_log UL ON U.c_user_id = UL.c_user_id GROUP BY U.c_user_id LIMIT 1)
UNION 
(SELECT U.c_user_level_id, UL.c_task_id FROM t_user U INNER JOIN t_user_log UL ON U.c_user_id = UL.c_user_id GROUP BY U.c_user_id LIMIT 1)
```

I am getting this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvGHR.png)

```
c_user_id              c_timestamp
1                      2018-04-12 04:12:50
99                     1
```

I want this as one row

```
c_user_id   c_timestamp           c_user_level_id       c_task_id 
1           2018-04-12 04:12:50   99                    1
```

Comment: What is the relation between your 2 tables? How do you want to join. Every row of table match like 1 to 1, 2  to 2 or?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to combine both table result by using join, after that insert it.

Have a look on sqlFiddle. 
[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ed136/1)

Hope this example will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the both queries the join is exactly same. The join condition and tables are same for join. So you can select all 4 columns in a single query instead of creating 2 different query and then trying to concat the results

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_temp_table 
(SELECT U.c_user_id, UL.c_timestamp, U.c_user_level_id, UL.c_task_id FROM t_user U INNER JOIN t_user_log UL ON U.c_user_id = UL.c_user_id GROUP BY U.c_user_id LIMIT 1);
```